# Definition of weakly compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

My book defines a weakly compact operator $T:X\to Y$ between Banach spaces as a continuous linear operator such that the closure of $T(B)$ is weakly compact for each $B\subset X$ bounded. My question is, is this closure in the norm or weak topology? I think I've also seen it defined to be such that $T(B)$ is relatively weakly compact, so I think it means the weak closure of $T(B)$ is compact in the weak topology.

Comment: Yes, it is the weak closure of $T(B)$.